# Why a lack of inversion in this sentence ?

Tags: inversion

I am used to seeing questions phrased like this:

> Combien la France compte-t-elle d'habitants ? Combien la France compte-t-elle de millionaires ?

But I came across a website page whose headline runs:

> Combien la France compte d'immigrés et d'étrangers ?

That lack of verb/pronoun inversion looks very strange to me. Or is it perfectly acceptable?

Answer (score 4):

Lack of inversion is now the norm in spoken French.

Here the written sentence would be considered relaxed by some people but I believe most find it perfectly acceptable as it reproduces what we could have say orally.

Comment: Let's say it's becoming more normal, but the "-t-elle" is not completely dead yet either? At least in written form. In spoken language, maybe something like "Y'a combien d'immigrés et d'étrangers en France?"

Comment: merci jlliagre - très utile :)

Comment: @Frank Yes, oral French can be even more relaxed but *Y'a combien [...]* is less likely to be written as the title of a web article, unless a special effect is requested.

Comment: @jlliagre Yes, I prefaced with "in spoken language" - I wouldn't see it in a title, for sure.