"Quelle chanson française tu préfères ?" Shouldn't this sentence be inverted?
I was reading this page and one example sentence stood out.

Voici la liste des chansons. Quelle chanson française tu préfères ?

I thought it would be ether "Quelle chanson française préfères-tu  ?" or "Quelle chanson française est-ce que tu préfères ?"
All the other examples seem to follow patterns I am familiar with:

Quel livre est-ce que tu lis ? 
Quel animal vois-tu ? 
Quel animal est-ce que tu vois ?

Why is it that the sentence at issue is neither inverted nor does it have "est-ce que"?

Because it's informal, familiar usage. Inverting would make the sentence "more correct", but people will use the non-inverted form too.

50 years ago, I would have say that was the written form of the sentence (without inversion) was incorrect. Today, it is widely accepted. When writing it, the question mark denotes the interrogation. In the oral form, the intonation makes the difference.

See also https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53527/why-a-lack-of-inversion-in-this-sentence

Note that as a foreigner (specially with a noticeable accent) you'll be quite welcome to use the inverted subject.
